# Create Listview in Tableview xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, cross-platform, tableview

I am not sure if I can add a list view inside the table section of the `TableView`.  I tried to search online but can't seemed to find any solutions to this.  Am I missing out some tags? Would appreciate if someone would be able to help me out one this.

```xml
<TableView x:Name="tableView">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection x:Name="blockSection" Title="Name">
            <ListView x:Name="lvFilter">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10">
                                            </ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250">
                                            </ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                                            </ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label x:Name="filterName" Text="{Binding filterName}” YAlign="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image x:Name="ImageL" Source="check_mark.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Aside from the TableView issue, you also have a superfluous StackLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to put the ListView inside a ViewCell.

```
<TableSection>
    <ViewCell>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Testing123"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Content>
    <ListView>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Xamarin Forms 2.3.3. `ListView.Content` doesn't exist, and using`ListView.ItemTemplate` doesn't seem to work.